Find the Hamiltonian of a relativistic particle with the temporal gauge
Recently I have been taking some classes in string theory, but I am a mathematician and generally I lack a lot of background. So in the study guide that was given to us by the seminarist there is the following problem which I solved partially (I think).

Given the action
$S=\int d\tau(p_{\mu}\dot{x}^{\mu}+e(p^{2}+m^{2}))$ calculate the Hamiltonian in the:
a) Temporal gauge  $\eta x^{\mu}=\tau$, $n^{2}=-1$.
b)Ligthcone gauge $\eta x^{\mu}=\tau$, $n^{2}=0$.

The first problem that I encountered is that the notation of the gauges is not understandable, and there is no reference in the study guide and this is not the notation that we saw in class. For instance, in class we saw that the light cone gauge was that $x^{+}=\tau$ which in turn implies $\dot{x}^{+}=1$, but I don't know what the $n^{2}$ means in the case given above. Maybe this is some physics notation that everyone knows and I am missing?

Considering this, this is my solution for the light cone gauge, did I do it right?
solution: Taking the parametration of the worldline $\tau$ we take the Lagrangian form the action given:
$$\mathscr{L}=p_{\mu}\dot{x}^{\mu}+e(p^{2}+m^{2})$$
where $p$ is the momentum, $\dot{x}$ the velocity and $e(\tau)$ the einbein.
In class we saw that
$$p^{2}=\eta^{\mu\nu}p_{\mu}p_{\nu}=-2p^{+}p^{-}+\sum_{A=2}p^{2}_{A}$$
(where $\eta=(+,-,-,\dots)$)
where we passed to lightcone coordinates. In addition to this we have the constraint:
$$p^{2}+m^{2}=-2p^{+}p^{-}+\sum_{A=2}p^{2}_{a}+m^{2}=0.$$
So, we rewrite the lagrangian applying the gauge $\dot{x}^{+}=1$:
$$\mathscr{L}=p_{+}+p_{-}\dot{x}^{-}+\sum_{A=2}p^{2}_{A}\dot{x}^{A}+e(-2p^{+}p^{-}+\sum_{A=2}p^{2}_{a}+m^{2})$$
Now, we want to find who is $e$ and $p^{-}$. For this we first do the variation of the Lagrangian with $p_{+}$ (considering we have that the identities: $p_{+}=-p^{-}, p_{-}=-p^{+}$) and get:
$$1=\frac{1}{2p^{+}}$$
Now variation with respect $e$ yields:
$$-2p^{+}p^{-}+\sum_{A=2}p^{2}_{a}+m^{2}=0$$
so from here we get that
$$p^{-}=-\frac{\sum_{A=2}p^{2}_{a}+m^{2}}{-2p^{+}}.$$
So then the hamiltonian is:
$$H=p_{+}+p_{-}\dot{x}^{-}+\sum_{A=2}p^{2}_{A}\dot{x}^{A}-\mathscr{L}=-e(-2p^{+}p^{-}+\sum_{A=2}p^{2}_{a}+m^{2})=-\frac{1}{2p^{+}}(-2p^{+}p^{-}+\sum_{A=2}p^{2}_{a}+m^{2}).$$
This is what i got but I'm not sure if it is right, especially because in no point I used the $n^{2}=0$.

Now for the Temporal gauge I tried to do something similar but I didn't manage, maybe I need to do a coordinate change that I am unaware of. Also the notation of the gauge is not that clear to me, but I suppose it means $\dot{x}^{0}=1$ as I mentioned in the comments. Any help will be appreciated.

Hi @AdrinMI49. Welcome to Phys.SE.  Comments to the post (v2): 1. The indices of some formulas do not match/are not explained. E.g. what is the meaning of $\eta x^{\mu}$? 2. Presumably OP's definition of temporal gauge is essentially $x^0=\tau$.

Related: Why don't people use Hamilton's equations for a relativistic free particle?

I'm not completely sure but I guess it $\eta=(-1,+1,\dots)$ is the metric. And $x^\mu$ is just the coordinate. So $\eta x^\mu$ are coordinates in the space we are working with the time component being negative. This is the interpretation that i got from my class. But the seminariat that gave this study guide didn't specify anything, even after I asked directly. As you can see i ignored completely that definition in the one that i think I solved l, but still I'm not sure is correctly done

Ok, so $\eta x^{\mu}$ transcribed to standard notation seems to be $x_{\mu}:=\eta_{\mu\nu} x^{\nu}$.
